# can't expose kubernetes service aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, flannel

i've automation deployment with jenkins to kubernetes using AWS ec2, but i can't access it

```
outside`ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-236:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
node-app-55b7788b4b-b5rrb   1/1     Running   2          22h
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-236:~$ kubectl get deployment
NAME       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
node-app   1/1     1            1           22h
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-236:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          7d17h
lb-service   LoadBalancer   10.109.120.200   <pending>     9005:31694/TCP   18h
```

i was trying ClusterIP, NodePort, and LoadBalancer but can't access it to internet. don't have external IP.

```
    Name:         node-app-55b7788b4b-b5rrb
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker01/172.31.2.82
Start Time:   Mon, 19 Sep 2022 08:10:23 +0000
Labels:       app=node-app
              pod-template-hash=55b7788b4b
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.46
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.46
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/node-app-55b7788b4b
Containers:
  node-app:
    Container ID:   docker://6b21adefe9d81f7ec96a7e50803aa999ea72aeaa09d5535b0757f19ac0a2a03a
    Image:          <harbor_url>/node/node-app:81
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://<harbor_url>/node/node-app@sha256:c1b7fbb01add4e6c89507b6413ce34d618d08629031fdc669fa05d0290d2e4b9
    Port:           9005/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 20 Sep 2022 06:08:50 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Mon, 19 Sep 2022 11:02:52 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 19 Sep 2022 11:31:27 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rjgl9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-rjgl9:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----               ----               -------
```

here's the service

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-236:~$ kubectl describe service lb-service
Name:                     lb-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=node-app
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.109.120.200
IPs:                      10.109.120.200
Port:                     <unset>  9005/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31694/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.1.46:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata:
  name: node-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-app
  replicas: 1 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-app
          image: <harbor_url>/node/node-app:$BUILD_NUMBER # Image that will be used to containers in the cluster
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9005 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: harbor-reg


---

apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata: # Metadata of the resource kind we are creating
  name: node-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: node-app
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 9005 # The port that the service is running on in the cluster
      targetPort: 80 # The port exposed by the service
  type: LoadBalancer # type of the service.
```

i using flanel for network policy

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-236:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default        node-app-55b7788b4b-b5rrb                  1/1     Running   2          22h
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-j88kj                      1/1     Running   6          7d18h
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-lb2cp                      1/1     Running   10         7d18h
kube-system    coredns-558bd4d5db-58kt2                   1/1     Running   7          7d18h
kube-system    coredns-558bd4d5db-mnsjl                   1/1     Running   8          7d18h
kube-system    etcd-ip-172-31-32-236                      1/1     Running   9          7d18h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-32-236            1/1     Running   8          7d18h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-32-236   1/1     Running   9          7d18h
kube-system    kube-proxy-4vv72                           1/1     Running   6          7d18h
kube-system    kube-proxy-qxtsz                           1/1     Running   9          7d18h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-32-236            1/1     Running   9          7d18h
```

also iam trying access it with public IP on worker node and master, but i find
dead end.

Answer (score 0):

After having Jenkins up and running with the ports exposed, you need to expose the application to the WEB. In order to do that you should create an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

But for more simplicity you can deploy jenkins using helm, see the following [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/deploying-jenkins-on-amazon-eks-with-amazon-efs/)

Comment: My jenkins up in another instance...i've 4 instance : jenkins, harbor private registry,  master and worker node... they all running and integrate each other...but at the final i can't access my app what i buld from the begining to the outside

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how did you install the Harbor.

First, you should create a load balancer in AWS with DNS harbor.local, then you could get it's external IP Address.

Second, deploy harbor with the loadBalancer settings.

```
git clone https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm
cd harbor-helm
helm install myrelease .  --set expose.type=loadBalancer,expose.tls.auto.commonName=harbor.local,externalURL=https://harbor.local
```

After deploy complete, you can add   harbor.local to your DNS or updating /etc/hosts of the client machine.

```
<IP address>  harbor.local
```

Then try login to harbor with

https://harbor.local

Comment: my harbor is okay my friend, i can access it with htpp and create secrete in kubernetes then can pull it. it;s working inside the pod, i can curl with pod ip, but not outside.  My problem is exposing my app that i created to the internet.
how i can get the aws DNS in my cluster?

Comment: The AWS DNS should be configured in LB, the LB could expose your internal service to the internet